# Binary to text in Java

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, nsstringencoding

I have a String with binary data in it (1110100) I want to get the text out so I can print it (1110100 would print "t"). I tried this, it is similar to what I used to transform my text to binary but it's not working at all:

```
    public static String toText(String info)throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        byte[] encoded = info.getBytes();
        String text = new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("print: "+text);
        return text;
    }
```

Any corrections or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a radix of 2 (binary) to convert the binary string to an integer:

```
int charCode = Integer.parseInt(info, 2);
```

Then if you want the corresponding character as a string:

```
String str = new Character((char)charCode).toString();
```

Comment: Thank you, it makes a lot of sense, but I don't understand how to make a new Character from an int (charCode)

Comment: @Nick: Just cast it to `char`.

Comment: can i name this thing as a vector representation of text ?

Comment: Does this work when the word in the byte is "0000" ?

Answer (score 9):

This is my one (Working fine on Java 8):

```
String input = "01110100"; // Binary input as String
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Some place to store the chars

Arrays.stream( // Create a Stream
    input.split("(?<=\\G.{8})") // Splits the input string into 8-char-sections (Since a char has 8 bits = 1 byte)
).forEach(s -> // Go through each 8-char-section...
    sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt(s, 2)) // ...and turn it into an int and then to a char
);

String output = sb.toString(); // Output text (t)
```

and the compressed method printing to console:

```
Arrays.stream(input.split("(?<=\\G.{8})")).forEach(s -> System.out.print((char) Integer.parseInt(s, 2))); 
System.out.print('\n');
```

I am sure there are "better" ways to do this but this is the smallest one you can probably get.

Answer (score 5):

I know the OP stated that their binary was in a `String` format but for the sake of completeness I thought I would add a solution to convert directly from a `byte[]` to an alphabetic String representation.

As *casablanca* stated you basically need to obtain the numerical representation of the alphabetic character. If you are trying to convert anything longer than a single character it will probably come as a `byte[]` and instead of converting that to a string and then using a for loop to append the characters of each `byte` you can use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and [CharBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) to do the lifting for you:

```
public static String bytesToAlphabeticString(byte[] bytes) {
    CharBuffer cb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asCharBuffer();
    return cb.toString();
}
```

***N.B. Uses UTF char set***

Alternatively using the String constructor:

```
String text = new String(bytes, 0, bytes.length, "ASCII");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static String binaryToText(String binary) {
    return Arrays.stream(binary.split("(?<=\\G.{8})"))/* regex to split the bits array by 8*/
                 .parallel()
                 .map(eightBits -> (char)Integer.parseInt(eightBits, 2))
                 .collect(
                                 StringBuilder::new,
                                 StringBuilder::append,
                                 StringBuilder::append
                 ).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way around (Where "info" is the input text and "s" the binary version of it)

```
byte[] bytes = info.getBytes();
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(bytes);
String s = bi.toString(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer.

```
private String[] splitByNumber(String s, int size) {
    return s.split("(?<=\\G.{"+size+"})");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`parseInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) function.  You may also need a cast and the [`Character.toString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29) function.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use alternative solution without streams and regular expressions ([based on casablanca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211732/8370915)):

```
public static String binaryToText(String binaryString) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int charCode;
    for (int i = 0; i < binaryString.length(); i += 8) {
        charCode = Integer.parseInt(binaryString.substring(i, i + 8), 2);
        String returnChar = Character.toString((char) charCode);
        stringBuilder.append(returnChar);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

you just need to [append](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String)) the specified character as a string to character sequence.