# Convert binary string to ascii text?

Tags: java, text, binary

I was wondering if it is possible to enter in binary numbers and have them translated back into text. For example I would enter "01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111" and it would covert it into the word "hello".

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211705/binary-to-text-in-java

Answer (score 8):

Just some logical corrections:

There are three steps here

1. Turning the binary set into an integer
2. Then the integer into a character
3. Then concatenate to the string you're building

Luckily `parseInt` takes a `radix` argument for the base.  So, once you either chop the string up into (presumably) an array of strings of length 8, *or* access the necessary substring, all you need to do is `(char)Integer.parseInt(s, 2)` and concatenate.

```
String s2 = "";   
char nextChar;

for(int i = 0; i <= s.length()-8; i += 9) //this is a little tricky.  we want [0, 7], [9, 16], etc (increment index by 9 if bytes are space-delimited)
{
     nextChar = (char)Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+8), 2);
     s2 += nextChar;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the answer to this question: [binary-to-text-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211705/binary-to-text-in-java).