# Using binary data in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, binary

My android application receive binary data as UDP packet , how should I convert that in android to ASCII ?

Comment: You can find the solution you want here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211705/binary-to-text-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```java
byte [] data = (however you extract data from your source);
String result = new String(data, "iso-8859-1");
```