# Converting a binary string to an ascii string, the long way (No API Functions)

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, ascii

I had an interview recently and discovered that I'd forgotten some of the basics.  I've been playing around again and have written a function that will take a binary string (there is no validation yet) and returns the ascii representation of said string.

I'm looking for advice or tips on how it could be improved. I don't want to use any of the API functions, this is more of a playground scenario in which I might be able to learn something.

Thanks for any help.

Sample output:

```
01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 
104
101
108
108
111
hello



public static String convertBinaryStringToString(String string){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = string.replaceAll("\\s", "").toCharArray();
    int [] mapping = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};

    for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j+=8) {
        int idx = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 7; i>= 0; i--) {
            if (chars[i+j] == '1') {
                sum += mapping[idx];
            }
            idx++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);//debug
        sb.append(Character.toChars(sum));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Someone else may correct me, but I think you have enough code to post here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Trobbins - would you like me to move the post, are you able to?  If not, is the 'way' to delete this one and paste as a question on the code review site?

Comment: And you don't want to use 

Integer.parseInt("10001001",2); ?

Comment: I don't have enough experience here to say one way or the other (I'm not 100% sure how much code is required for CR)... but I think it would be okay to post in both places for now. 

My reasoning is that since you're looking to improve upon working code, CR should be fine.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov, no, it's a exercise to simply see if I could.  I was asked to reveres a string and parse an int as well as others in this interview, I was successful but it still made me very aware that I had forgotten many things :)

Comment: @Trobbins, thanks, I'll post in the other site and remove one or the other once something happens. :)

Comment: Similar post [here][1] with multiple answers and approaches.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211705/binary-to-text-in-java

Comment: @AdrianTeh, thanks, I've visited that page before, I don't wish to use API functions.

Comment: @SteveGreen "I don't wish to use API functions." Aren't you doing that with `Character.toChars` ?

Comment: @MadConan, would you believe me if I said I was now 'googling' for an alternative way?  Have you anything else that might be productive or useful?

Comment: @SteveGreen I do believe you, I don't have an alternative.  Since this is an exercise, you'll basically have to duplicate the code in `Character.toChars`.  You could take your own shot at it first or look at the source now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an array with the powers of two - the computer already knows them and you can use `1<<k` to get the k-th power of two. However you don't need that either. Here is a short function to parse int from a char array that is the binary representation of a number. With a little modification the code will work for any base up to 10.

```
public static int parseBinary(char[] chars) {
  int res = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    res *= 2;
    if (chars[i] == '1') {
      res += 1;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Using this function you can simplify your code significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more java8-ish solution:

```
public static String convertBinaryStringToString(String string) {
    return stream(string.split("\\s+"))
            .mapToInt(s -> s.chars().reduce(0, (x, y) -> (char) (x * 2 + (y-'0'))))
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
}
```