# How can I convert ASCII to character in android?

Tags: android

I'm a self android learner. I want to convert ascii code to character.
Here is the code I used.

```
     String s = "1000001";
     int num = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);
     TextView textView = new TextView(this);
     textView.setText(String.valueOf(num));
     setContentView(textView);
```

Here s is 1000001(65 in decimal) 65 is ascii value of 'A'. I want to get 'A' in my output screen.variable num has the value 65. please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211705/binary-to-text-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert ASCII code (0-255) to a String of the associated character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693994/how-to-convert-ascii-code-0-255-to-a-string-of-the-associated-character)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code

```
Character.toString ((char) num);
```

Comment: if  i'm giving like this ..It does not work..                                                               String s = "100";
int num = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);                                                                                   plz suggest a method to work both cases(charater and number)